# Append 'Continue Reading' link if post length is more than 3 lines of text in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, post, blogs

I'm pretty new to coding for Wordpress, bear with me.

I have a section on my home page, that lists the 2 most recent blog posts.

If the text goes past three lines, my design gets messed up. So I was wondering if there was a native function that exists for me to append 'Continue Reading' automagically and allow the user to click that link to bring them to the full blog post?

For example, this is what I do NOT want:

[image: Bad]

This, is what I do want, I did the design in Photoshop and this is what I'd like to happen if the posts are going to be longer than 3 lines of text.

[image: Good]

Thanks, I'll try to clarify anything if need be!

Comment: Very nice to have mock-ups, but you need to show your research and attempted solutions. Anyway, define *3 lines*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show the excerpt instead of the full post.

Replace:

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

with:

```
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
```

Now to control the length of the excerpt, you need to add this snippet in your functions.php file

http://pastebin.com/tncRhSL2

Source: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing the lines, I would try to go for characters or words. The example below uses characters.

Don't take my word on it as it hasn't been tested.

```
$character == 40; // number of characters to compare
if(mb_strlen( get_the_content() ) < $character){
the_content();
}else{
the_content('Continue Reading...')
}
```

If you would like to compare it to word count you can use str_word_count(get_the_content(), 0)

Comment: Thanks Andre, 

I will attempt this, and let you know if I have any questions! If not I'll mark as answer and post my solution.

Comment: I've tried this, using the following code:

`<div class="post_text">`
`<?php`
`$words == 20; // number of characters to compare`      `if(str_word_count(get_the_content(),0)  < $words){ //if str_word count is less than words`
`the_content();} //display the content normally`
`else{the_content('Continue Reading...');} //otherwise, change it to continue reading`
`?>`

Which, didn't work. I had to change a line or two to make the theme not fail, but no matter what value I assigned to $words nothing happened. 

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you place it in the loop?

Comment: Yes:

http://pastebin.com/ZmAJKNBL

Is my code without your changes. 

I replaced <?php the_content(); ?> with your code (and my modifications) and after breaking initially it was fixed with my changes but had no affect on the output.

Hopefully the pastebin makes things easier, as that ^ code is hard to digest in that format!

Comment: my the_content exists on line 20 in the pastebin, just an FYI!

Comment: I'll look into this tomorrow.

Comment: I appreciate your help thus far! Talk to you tomorrow!